# To Fetch Service Request Form URL from Remedy / Digital Work Place / SmartIT

Tags: json, remedy

We have a standalone web application which has a list of links that redirects the users to (SmartIT / Other Internal Web Applications). These links are picked from a JSON File.

```
{
   "title" : "BMC Remedy",
    "link" : "https://www.bmc.com/"
},
{
    "title" : "Password Rest",
     "link" : "https://smartit.com/reset"
}
```

Now we are heading for a Remedy Upgrade which results in URL Change of all these Links (Close to 400). Is there any way to fetch a report of all SmartIT form URL's. Else we have to this manually.

I tried using `srd_url` field in `SRD:ServiceRequestDefinition`, but the report did not give any results.

Answer (score 0):

The newer Version's SRD ID is same across all of the newer version platfrom (PERF, QA and PROD). We have migrated it by changing the prefix (www.***perf.myorg.com/#SRDID) and kept the IDs same.